# Не появляется панель управления плеером в Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, видео, online-video

Здравствуйте!
Вот есть CSS стили для панели плеера в полноэкранном режиме:

```js
// В JS та же история:
vid.controls = false;
vid.oncontextmenu = function(){return false;};
```

```css
video::-webkit-media-controls,
video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
    display:none !important;
} 
/* Скрываем стандартные элементы управления */

/* Стили для блока в полноэкранном режиме */

.fullscreen {
    /* Нужно для того, что бы избежать проблем с z-index для стандартного блока управления видео в user agent stylesheet */
    z-index: 2789034264 !important;
    /* Нужно для того, что бы избежать проблем с z-index для стандартного блока управления видео в user agent stylesheet */; 
    position: absolute !important;
    width: 80% !important;
    bottom: 5.7% !important;
    left: 10% !important;
    right: 10% !important;
    height: 35px !important;
}
```

Это код для Chrome и Opera. А каким будет код для скрытия стандартной панели плеера в Firefox и Safari? И еще: как отобразить мою кастомную панель в Firefox? `z-index` не работает.

Comment: обычно видео просто накрывают слоем сверху и не думают о такой ерунде.

Comment: @zb' Так вот я так и делаю. У меня в Хроме и Опере все норм, но в Safari есть стандартная панель, а в Firefox в полноэкранном режиме панель не показывается.

Comment: Вам необходимо в теге видео установить аттрибут controls='false'

Comment: @DStrokov Да, спасибо это помогло. Но ответьте уже в виде ответа а не комментария, как отобразить мой пульт управления плеером в Firefox. Если все будет чётко, то 50 баллов ваши.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для скрытия стандартной панели, воспользуйтесь аттрибутом controls='false'в теге video. Проблема с отображением в fullscreen возможно связана с особенностями fullscreenmode в FF, попробуйте обернуть видео и контролы в wrapper и уже его показывать на весь экран. 
Примерно так:

```
document.getElementById("videoWrapper").requestFullScreen();
```

Честно говоря не рекомендовал бы вам изобретать свой велосипед, можно собрать много шишек в борьбе с кроссбраузерностью, воспользуйтесь готовыми обкатанными решениями. Отличный пример c поддержкой полной кастомизации [videojs](http://videojs.com/)

Comment: Это то да, но сама фишка, что z-index в FF игнорируется, и панелька все равно не отображается поверх видео. Вот в чем тут дело.

Comment: Я собрал небольшой пример который работает с кастомными контролами в FF вообще без использования CSS - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XRWogX попробуйте, должно помочь вам. Проверил у себя на маке в FF nightly - все ок, в фулскрин режиме вместе с контролами показывается.